# Visualizing vectors in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose a certain matrix, $A$, contains vectors $v_n$, with $x$ number of elements. Let's say there are two independent vectors ($v_1$ and $v_2$) with $2$ elements each. Visually this forms a plane in $R^2$.

Now let's say we have a matrix $B$, a $2$ x $3$ matrix. Now how would I go about visualizing $B$? Can I just take the transpose of $B$ ($B^T$) and make it a $3$ x $2$ and visualize it as a subspace in $R^3$?

Just scratching linear algebra here. These are thoughts and ideas I had questions about.

Comment: If you have two independent vectors with two elements each, their span isn’t just “a plane in $\mathbb R^2$,” it *is* $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you want to visualize.

If you want to visualize some elements of the column space, then each column is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and you can plot $3$ vectors there.

If you are interested in visualizing some elements of the row space, then each row is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$,  and you have two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I understand that but how would $B$ *look*? Is there a way to visualize a $3$ x $2$ matrix? Also, is the column space just the transpose of row space and vice versa? Could you clarify?

Comment: If $B$ is of full rank, then the column space is the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose not and there is a non-zero column, then it is a line. Otherwise it is just the origin. To visulize $3 \times 2$, go $3D$.  For the last question, I am not sure whether people use the term transpose for space. but if you know how to handle columns, when you want to handle row, just transpose it.